# Coalesce pulling zero as value

Tags: mysql, coalesce

this is driving me crazy!

I have three tables. The first table has a list of all records along with other data (region, dates, etc). The 2nd and 3rd tables have all the hours/cost data, but the 2nd table contains only historical records, and the 3rd table contains newer records. I want my coalesce to try to find a value in the newer records first, but if no record is found, to look in the historic table. For some reason, even though i KNOW there is a value in the historic table, the result of my coalesce is coming in as 0.

```
Table1

ID     Region 
1        US 
2        US 
3        Europe 
4        US 
5        Europe 
6        US

Table2

ID     Hours
1        10
2        15
3        20


Table3

ID     Hours
4        3
5        7
6        4
```

So, my statement is written like this:

`SELECT
t1.ID,
COALESCE(t3.hours, t2.hours) AS HOURS
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
LEFT JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.ID=t3.ID`

Now, for some reason, if the value is found in t3 (the newer records) it pulls in the correct value, but if it does not find a value and has to pull in a value from t2, it is pulling in a 0 instead of the actual value. Result looks like this:

```
ID     HOURS
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        3
5        7
6        4
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the column type in table 2 (I have all column settings as VARCHAR(55), but I can't find any rules around data types in coalesce function about having to use only a certain column type with coalesce.

Appreciate any guidance!

edited to add results for Spencer's inquiry:

```
ID      t2.hours + 0   t2.hours   hex(t2.hours)   length(t2.hours)
413190    240          240            F0                 3
```

Comment: shouldn't the `on` for the last table join be `t1.id=t3.id`? or is that just a typo?

Comment: Your query looks fine.  Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3f43/5/0) showing it works.  I think you have a data problem somewhere that's being obfuscated by your question

Comment: You say column `hours` in `t2` is VARCHAR(55).  The values of the expressions look right, `'240'` as a character string, has a length of 3 bytes, and evaluates to numeric value of `240`. The output from HEX is strange. If this column is latin1 characterset, definitely expect that to return `323430`. The return of `F0` is very odd. Interpreted as an integer value (TINYINT) that's equal to decimal (15*16)+(0*1) = `240`. Very strange. What is the characterset of the `hours` column? What version of MySQL? (output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table2` and output from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version%'`

Comment: My apologies - i had been playing around with characterset types when I was trying to troubleshoot, and had changed the type to decimal (10,0). When I changed it back to VARCHAR and reran the SQL query it presented the HEX value as `323430` (as you said it should).

Comment: There's something else going on. I setup a test case on MySQL 5.6, using the exact data you showed, and tested with `hours` as both `INT` and `VARCHAR` types. I wasn't able to replicate the behavior you describe.  I'd be tempted to make sure both expressions in the COALESCE are numeric, implicit conversion using the "plus zero" trick,,, `COALESCE(t3.hours + 0, t2.hours + 0)`  But there's something else going on, other than a mismatch of datatypes.

Comment: I had another thought. In my setup, Table2 is a table, and Table3 is a view. All the values are pulling in fine when the value resides in Table2 (a table) but pulling in with a value of 0 when they come from Table3 (a view). Am I not allowed to coalesce between a column in a table and a column in a view?

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect joins:

```
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
                              ^
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
                              ^
```

you're joining table 3 using values from table 2

Comment: Marc B - you are correct that my join statement was wrong in my example, but unfortunately that was just an oops when I was setting everything up to ask the question (i've edited it). In my actual SQL query, the joins are all perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the evaluation of `t2.hours` in the `COALESCE` function is being done in *numeric* context, and the values stored in the `hours` column are evaluating to a numeric value of `0`.

One quick way to check what numeric that evaluates to is to add a zero, as in the first expression in this query:

```
 SELECT t2.hours + 0 
      , t2.hours
      , HEX(t2.hours)
      , LENGTH(t2.hours)
   FROM table2 t2
```

I'm curious what that query shows for one of the rows that's returning a `0` from the COALESCE expression, whether the numeric evaluation is returning 0, and whether there's any leading wonky characters in the column value.

Comment: Hi Spencer7593, Doing the above on the real life columns in my real life database, I got the following result on one of the records that is exhibiting the behavior in question. Some of the rows have hex that are all number, and some have alphanumeric values (as this id does): 

    ID        t2.hours + 0     t2.hours     hex(t2.hours)     length(t2.hours)
    413190    240                  240                F0                         3

Not sure what that F0 indicates.

Comment: i edited my question above to show what results I got from your check. It wouldn't let me add in the comments without goofy formatting :)